# Not getting past the login screen

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu then rebooted my laptop. From there, I booted up with Ubuntu instead of Windows 7 and it took me to a loading screen, saying launching for first time or something. Then it took me to a login screen where I then typed in my password then it just stayed at this (see image below).

[image]

I could move my mouse but nothing else.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Have you tried rebooting again?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try booting into "Recovery Mode" when you see the Grub menu. From there you could try to boot with failsafe graphics and see if that works.

Also, what graphics card do you have? If you have a relatively modern ATI card, you might have success by installing the fglrx driver. Boot again into "Recovery Mode" and then choose root shell with networking. Then type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: For Graphics card I have a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 with 320 MB memory.  I'm going to try what you said now I'll be right back.